# java.lang.NullPointerException - Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, tabs, oncreate

I created a tabactivity and the problem is that, the activity I intent never showed. in short, it's blank white page and when i clicked on the second tab, the app forces closes leaving an error of a NullPointerExcpetion. How can I fix this?

This is the TabActivity

```
public class FMSTab extends TabActivity {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.tablistener);
Resources res = getResources();
TabHost tb = getTabHost();
TabHost.TabSpec spec;
Intent inten;
inten = new Intent().setClass(this, FileManagingSystemDetails.class);
spec = tb.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Command",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_lcomm))
.setContent(inten);
tb.addTab(spec);
inten = new Intent().setClass(this, Terminal.class);
spec =    tb.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Terminal",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_terminal))
.setContent(inten);
tb.addTab(spec);

tb.setCurrentTab(0);
}
}
```

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dp">
<TabWidget
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<FrameLayout
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Updated logcat

```
01-22 21:16:20.817: E/Term(8753): onCreate
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jackpal.androidterm/jackpal.androidterm.Term}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2234)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2075)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:694)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:358)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:150)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:546)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17072)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5042)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at jackpal.androidterm.Term.onCreate(Term.java:274)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
01-22 21:16:20.994: E/AndroidRuntime(8753):     ... 18 more
```

Here is the code in my first tab.

```
public class FileManagingSystemDetails extends Activity {
TextView name,desc,syntax,option;
int id;
DBHelper dbhelper;  
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.command_desc);

        //database
        id = getIntent().getIntExtra("COMMAND_ID", 0);
        SQLiteDatabase db = (new DBHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();

       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT comm_filems.name, comm_filems.desc, comm_filems.syntax, comm_filems.option FROM comm_filems WHERE comm_filems._id = ?", 
                new String[]{""+id});

        if (cursor.getCount() == 1)
        {
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                name = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.name);
                name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
                Typeface custom_font_name = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                        "fonts/segoeui.ttf");
                        name.setTypeface(custom_font_name);

                desc = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.desc);
                desc.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("desc")));
                Typeface custom_font_desc = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                        "fonts/segoeui.ttf");
                        desc.setTypeface(custom_font_desc);

                syntax = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.syntax);
                syntax.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("syntax")));
                Typeface custom_font_syntax = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                        "fonts/segoeui.ttf");
                        syntax.setTypeface(custom_font_syntax);

                option = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.option);
                option.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("option")));
                Typeface custom_font_option = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                        "fonts/segoeui.ttf");
                        option.setTypeface(custom_font_option);

        }

    }

    }
```

Here is the code for my second tab

```
public class Term extends Activity {
/**
 * The ViewFlipper which holds the collection of EmulatorView widgets.
 */
private TermViewFlipper mViewFlipper;

/**
 * The name of the ViewFlipper in the resources.
 */
private static final int VIEW_FLIPPER = R.id.view_flipper;

private SessionList mTermSessions;

private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
private TermSettings mSettings;

private final static int SELECT_TEXT_ID = 0;
private final static int COPY_ALL_ID = 1;
private final static int PASTE_ID = 2;
private final static int SEND_CONTROL_KEY_ID = 3;
private final static int SEND_FN_KEY_ID = 4;

private boolean mAlreadyStarted = false;
private boolean mStopServiceOnFinish = false;

private Intent TSIntent;

public static final int REQUEST_CHOOSE_WINDOW = 1;
public static final String EXTRA_WINDOW_ID = "jackpal.androidterm.window_id";
private int onResumeSelectWindow = -1;

private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
private WifiManager.WifiLock mWifiLock;
// Available on API 12 and later
private static final int WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF = 3;

private boolean mBackKeyPressed;

private static final String ACTION_PATH_BROADCAST = "jackpal.androidterm.broadcast.APPEND_TO_PATH";
private static final String ACTION_PATH_PREPEND_BROADCAST = "jackpal.androidterm.broadcast.PREPEND_TO_PATH";
private static final String PERMISSION_PATH_BROADCAST = "jackpal.androidterm.permission.APPEND_TO_PATH";
private static final String PERMISSION_PATH_PREPEND_BROADCAST = "jackpal.androidterm.permission.PREPEND_TO_PATH";
private int mPendingPathBroadcasts = 0;
private BroadcastReceiver mPathReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String path = makePathFromBundle(getResultExtras(false));
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PATH_PREPEND_BROADCAST)) {
            mSettings.setPrependPath(path);
        } else {
            mSettings.setAppendPath(path);
        }
        mPendingPathBroadcasts--;

        if (mPendingPathBroadcasts <= 0 && mTermService != null) {
            populateViewFlipper();
           // populateWindowList();
        }
    }
};
// Available on API 12 and later
private static final int FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES = 0x20;

private TermService mTermService;
private ServiceConnection mTSConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        Log.i(TermDebug.LOG_TAG, "Bound to TermService");
        TermService.TSBinder binder = (TermService.TSBinder) service;
        mTermService = binder.getService();
        if (mPendingPathBroadcasts <= 0) {
            populateViewFlipper();
           // populateWindowList();
        }
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mTermService = null;
    }
};

private boolean mHaveFullHwKeyboard = false;

private class EmulatorViewGestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    private EmulatorView view;

    public EmulatorViewGestureListener(EmulatorView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        float absVelocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
        float absVelocityY = Math.abs(velocityY);
        if (absVelocityX > Math.max(1000.0f, 2.0 * absVelocityY)) {
            // Assume user wanted side to side movement
            if (velocityX > 0) {
                // Left to right swipe -- previous window
                mViewFlipper.showPrevious();
            } else {
                // Right to left swipe -- next window
                mViewFlipper.showNext();
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

private boolean mUseKeyboardShortcuts;

private View.OnKeyListener mKeyListener = new View.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return backkeyInterceptor(keyCode, event) || keyboardShortcuts(keyCode, event);
    }

    private boolean backkeyInterceptor(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Keyboard shortcuts (tab management, paste)
     */
    private boolean keyboardShortcuts(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!mUseKeyboardShortcuts) {
            return false;
        }
        boolean isCtrlPressed = (event.getMetaState() & KeycodeConstants.META_CTRL_ON) != 0;
        boolean isShiftPressed = (event.getMetaState() & KeycodeConstants.META_SHIFT_ON) != 0;

        if (keyCode == KeycodeConstants.KEYCODE_TAB && isCtrlPressed) {
            if (isShiftPressed) {
                mViewFlipper.showPrevious();
            } else {
                mViewFlipper.showNext();
            }

            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeycodeConstants.KEYCODE_N && isCtrlPressed && isShiftPressed) {
            doCreateNewWindow();

            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeycodeConstants.KEYCODE_V && isCtrlPressed && isShiftPressed) {
            doPaste();

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


};

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    Log.e(TermDebug.LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
    mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mSettings = new TermSettings(getResources(), mPrefs);

    Intent broadcast = new Intent(ACTION_PATH_BROADCAST);
    if (AndroidCompat.SDK >= 12) {
        broadcast.addFlags(FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
    }
    mPendingPathBroadcasts++;
    sendOrderedBroadcast(broadcast, PERMISSION_PATH_BROADCAST, mPathReceiver, null, RESULT_OK, null, null);

    broadcast = new Intent(broadcast);
    broadcast.setAction(ACTION_PATH_PREPEND_BROADCAST);
    mPendingPathBroadcasts++;
    sendOrderedBroadcast(broadcast, PERMISSION_PATH_PREPEND_BROADCAST, mPathReceiver, null, RESULT_OK, null, null);

    TSIntent = new Intent(this, TermService.class);
    startService(TSIntent);

    if (!bindService(TSIntent, mTSConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE)) {
        Log.w(TermDebug.LOG_TAG, "bind to service failed!");
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.term_activity);
    mViewFlipper = (TermViewFlipper) findViewById(VIEW_FLIPPER);


  //ActionBar
    ActionBar mActionBar = this.getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_ttg, null);
    TextView mTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_ttg);
    mTextView.setText("TERMINAL");
    Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
              "fonts/segoeui.ttf");
              mTextView.setTypeface(custom_font);

    mTextView.setTextSize(18);
    mTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);


    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TermDebug.LOG_TAG);
    WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    int wifiLockMode = WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL;
    if (AndroidCompat.SDK >= 12) {
        wifiLockMode = WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF;
    }
    mWifiLock = wm.createWifiLock(wifiLockMode, TermDebug.LOG_TAG);

    mHaveFullHwKeyboard = checkHaveFullHwKeyboard(getResources().getConfiguration());

    updatePrefs();
    mAlreadyStarted = true;
}

private String makePathFromBundle(Bundle extras) {
    if (extras == null || extras.size() == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    String[] keys = new String[extras.size()];
    keys = extras.keySet().toArray(keys);
    Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
    Arrays.sort(keys, collator);

    StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();
    for (String key : keys) {
        String dir = extras.getString(key);
        if (dir != null && !dir.equals("")) {
            path.append(dir);
            path.append(":");
        }
    }

    return path.substring(0, path.length()-1);
}

private void populateViewFlipper() {
    if (mTermService != null) {
        mTermSessions = mTermService.getSessions();
       // mTermSessions.addCallback(this);

        if (mTermSessions.size() == 0) {
            mTermSessions.add(createTermSession());
        }

        for (TermSession session : mTermSessions) {
            EmulatorView view = createEmulatorView(session);
            mViewFlipper.addView(view);
        }

        updatePrefs();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int flags = intent.getFlags();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if ((flags & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) == 0 &&
                action != null) {
            if (action.equals(RemoteInterface.PRIVACT_OPEN_NEW_WINDOW)) {
                mViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(mTermSessions.size()-1);
            } else if (action.equals(RemoteInterface.PRIVACT_SWITCH_WINDOW)) {
                int target = intent.getIntExtra(RemoteInterface.PRIVEXTRA_TARGET_WINDOW, -1);
                if (target >= 0) {
                    mViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(target);
                }
            }
        }

        mViewFlipper.resumeCurrentView();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mViewFlipper.removeAllViews();
    unbindService(mTSConnection);
    if (mStopServiceOnFinish) {
        stopService(TSIntent);
    }
    mTermService = null;
    mTSConnection = null;
    if (mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
        mWakeLock.release();
    }
    if (mWifiLock.isHeld()) {
        mWifiLock.release();
    }
}


protected static TermSession createTermSession(Context context, TermSettings settings, String initialCommand) {
    ShellTermSession session = new ShellTermSession(settings, initialCommand);
    // XXX We should really be able to fetch this from within TermSession
    session.setProcessExitMessage(context.getString(R.string.process_exit_message));

    return session;
}

private TermSession createTermSession() {
    TermSettings settings = mSettings;
    TermSession session = createTermSession(this, settings, settings.getInitialCommand());
    session.setFinishCallback(mTermService);
    return session;
}

private TermView createEmulatorView(TermSession session) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    TermView emulatorView = new TermView(this, session, metrics);

    emulatorView.setExtGestureListener(new EmulatorViewGestureListener(emulatorView));
    emulatorView.setOnKeyListener(mKeyListener);
    registerForContextMenu(emulatorView);

    return emulatorView;
}

private TermSession getCurrentTermSession() {
    SessionList sessions = mTermSessions;
    if (sessions == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return sessions.get(mViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild());
    }
}

private EmulatorView getCurrentEmulatorView() {
    return (EmulatorView) mViewFlipper.getCurrentView();
}

private void updatePrefs() {
    mUseKeyboardShortcuts = mSettings.getUseKeyboardShortcutsFlag();

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    mViewFlipper.updatePrefs(mSettings);

    for (View v : mViewFlipper) {
        ((EmulatorView) v).setDensity(metrics);
        ((TermView) v).updatePrefs(mSettings);
    }

    if (mTermSessions != null) {
        for (TermSession session : mTermSessions) {
            ((ShellTermSession) session).updatePrefs(mSettings);
        }
    }

    {

        Window win = getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = win.getAttributes();

    int orientation = mSettings.getScreenOrientation();
    int o = 0;
    if (orientation == 0) {
        o = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED;
    } else if (orientation == 1) {
        o = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
    } else if (orientation == 2) {
        o = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    } else {
        /* Shouldn't be happened. */
    }
    setRequestedOrientation(o);
}
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
          //  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(token, 0);
        }
    }.start();
}

private boolean checkHaveFullHwKeyboard(Configuration c) {
    return (c.keyboard == Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY) &&
        (c.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO);
}
private void doCreateNewWindow() {
    if (mTermSessions == null) {
        Log.w(TermDebug.LOG_TAG, "Couldn't create new window because mTermSessions == null");
        return;
    }

    TermSession session = createTermSession();
    mTermSessions.add(session);

    TermView view = createEmulatorView(session);
    view.updatePrefs(mSettings);

    mViewFlipper.addView(view);
    mViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(mViewFlipper.getChildCount()-1);
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int request, int result, Intent data) {
    switch (request) {
    case REQUEST_CHOOSE_WINDOW:
        if (result == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            int position = data.getIntExtra(EXTRA_WINDOW_ID, -2);
            if (position >= 0) {
                onResumeSelectWindow = position;
            } else if (position == -1) {
                doCreateNewWindow();
                onResumeSelectWindow = mTermSessions.size() - 1;
            }
        } else {
            if (mTermSessions == null || mTermSessions.size() == 0) {
                mStopServiceOnFinish = true;
                finish();
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if ((intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) != 0) {
        return;
    }

    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (action.equals(RemoteInterface.PRIVACT_OPEN_NEW_WINDOW)) {
        SessionList sessions = mTermSessions;
        if (sessions == null) {
            return;
        }
        int position = sessions.size() - 1;

        TermSession session = sessions.get(position);
        EmulatorView view = createEmulatorView(session);

        mViewFlipper.addView(view);
        onResumeSelectWindow = position;
    } else if (action.equals(RemoteInterface.PRIVACT_SWITCH_WINDOW)) {
        int target = intent.getIntExtra(RemoteInterface.PRIVEXTRA_TARGET_WINDOW, -1);
        if (target >= 0) {
            onResumeSelectWindow = target;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
  menu.setHeaderTitle(R.string.edit_text);
  menu.add(0, SELECT_TEXT_ID, 0, R.string.select_text);
  menu.add(0, COPY_ALL_ID, 0, R.string.copy_all);
  menu.add(0, PASTE_ID, 0,  R.string.paste);
  menu.add(0, SEND_CONTROL_KEY_ID, 0, R.string.send_control_key);
  menu.add(0, SEND_FN_KEY_ID, 0, R.string.send_fn_key);
  if (!canPaste()) {
      menu.getItem(PASTE_ID).setEnabled(false);
  }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case SELECT_TEXT_ID:
        getCurrentEmulatorView().toggleSelectingText();
        return true;
      case COPY_ALL_ID:
        doCopyAll();
        return true;
      case PASTE_ID:
        doPaste();
        return true;
      case SEND_CONTROL_KEY_ID:
        doSendControlKey();
        return true;
      case SEND_FN_KEY_ID:
        doSendFnKey();
        return true;
      default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
      }
    }

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (AndroidCompat.SDK < 5 && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        mBackKeyPressed = true;
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
public void onUpdate() {
    SessionList sessions = mTermSessions;
    if (sessions == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (sessions.size() == 0) {
        mStopServiceOnFinish = true;
        finish();
    } else if (sessions.size() < mViewFlipper.getChildCount()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mViewFlipper.getChildCount(); ++i) {
            EmulatorView v = (EmulatorView) mViewFlipper.getChildAt(i);
            if (!sessions.contains(v.getTermSession())) {
                v.onPause();
                mViewFlipper.removeView(v);
                --i;
            }
        }
    }
}

private boolean canPaste() {
    ClipboardManagerCompat clip = ClipboardManagerCompatFactory
            .getManager(getApplicationContext());
    if (clip.hasText()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}



private void doCopyAll() {
    ClipboardManagerCompat clip = ClipboardManagerCompatFactory
            .getManager(getApplicationContext());
    clip.setText(getCurrentTermSession().getTranscriptText().trim());
}

private void doPaste() {
    if (!canPaste()) {
        return;
    }
    ClipboardManagerCompat clip = ClipboardManagerCompatFactory
            .getManager(getApplicationContext());
    CharSequence paste = clip.getText();
    getCurrentTermSession().write(paste.toString());
}

private void doSendControlKey() {
    getCurrentEmulatorView().sendControlKey();
}

private void doSendFnKey() {
    getCurrentEmulatorView().sendFnKey();
}

}
```

Comment: problem is in `Term` class so add `Term` class code with post

Comment: problem is in your Activity onCreate not in this Class Check onCreate of both activity by debugging

Comment: I already added the codes. Please check again. Thanks

Comment: @Ace123: which is line number 371 in `Term.java` class ?

Comment: I updated my logcat. The 274 in Term is mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

Comment: i think problem should be in getactionbar() method.

Comment: Yes. The problem is around the actionbar. But why does the first tab gives a blank white page? :\